# How to read Multiple string lines from user console input?

Tags: c++, string

I have been trying to solve a problem which require unknown number of string inputs.
Below is my code which is not working as required. I just need help in how to take input of multiple lines.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void solve(string s)
{
    // cout << "String is : " << s << endl;
    stack<char> stk;
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == '[')
            stk.push(s[i]);
        else if(s[i] == ' ')
        {
            if(stk.top() == s[i])
                stk.pop();
            else
                stk.push(s[i]);
        }
        else if(s[i] == ']')
        {
            if(stk.top() == ' ')
                stk.pop();
            if(stk.top() == '[')
                stk.pop();
        }
    }
    cout << (stk.empty()? "YES" : "NO");
    // while(!stk.empty())
    // {
    //     cout << stk.top();
    //     stk.pop();
    // }
    // cout << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    string s;
    while(getline(cin, s))
    {
        solve(s);
    }
}
```

Input is given below.

```
    Input is :
    [] [ [ ] ]
    [ []]
    [] ]
    ][
```

But I am not able to read multiple lines.
As In my code there is a commented line (at the beginning of solve function) 
 **cout << "String is : " << s << endl;** . This line not giving output for any string input (Don't worry I know I have to decomment it).
What is the mistake in taking input for the strings?
Thank You..

Comment: **Related:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 0):

Your multiline input thing is working just fine : [Sample Run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ORHynF9LR2PErmr4).

You aren't getting any output probably because of segmentation fault : [Sample Run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ublGNGbnZVrfqd81).

To fix it, just change all your conditions calling `stk.top()` like : `if(stk.top() == ' ')`, with something like: `if(not stk.empty() and stk.top() == ' ')`, i.e. first check if the stack is not empty then call `stk.top()` : [Sample Run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0ofm8Ea1Z9aXSQg1).